# How to manage internal state in a Haskell modular application?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I am following the advise presented [on this video by Ben Kolera](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzouxmWiemg) for structuring modular Haskell applications.

It is suggested to have multiple monad transformers to make the application modular and organized. Use of custom `liftModule` functions is suggested to compose these monads together.

For example, we have a main `App` module and a `Logic` module.

```hs
newtype App a = App
  { unApp :: ExceptT AppError (ReaderT AppEnv IO) a }

newtype Logic a = Logic
  { unLogic :: ExceptT LogicError (Reader LogicEnv) a }
```

`liftLogic` is defined as follows.

```hs
runLogic :: LogicEnv -> Logic a -> Either LogicError a

liftLogic :: Logic a -> App a
liftLogic l = do 
  c <- asks appEnvLogic
  either (throwError . AppLogicError) pure $ runLogic c l
```

With this approach, how do I give a module an internal state? If I put a `StateT LogicState` in `Logic` transformer then won't `liftMonad` run monad completely thus unwrapping it and destroying its internal state?

The only way I see is to leak the internal state of `Logic` to `App` which I think is anti-modularity as it forces `App` to take care of `Logic`'s state.

Comment: I think it will be helpful to get a bit more specific with the details here. Maybe you could sketch what you are thinking about in code, give some hypothetical type signatures and the way you see the problem surfacing.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785379/how-do-you-structure-a-stateful-module-in-haskell?rq=1 is what I am asking here. I like the answer on that question.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `App` already "takes care" of `LogicEnv` and `LogicError`, so I think the anti-modularity ship has sailed.

Anyway, to run a stateful `Logic` in an `App`, you'll need to get an initial `LogicState` from somewhere and decide what to do with it once the `Logic` action is done.  In particular, if you want to be able to separately lift two `Logic` actions into `App` and have them thread the `LogicState`, then `App` will need to be stateful, too, with `LogicState` buried somewhere in the `AppState`.

So, the answer is probably something like:

```
newtype App a = App
  { unApp :: ExceptT AppError (StateT AppState (ReaderT AppEnv IO)) a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader AppEnv, 
            MonadState AppState, MonadError AppError)

newtype Logic a = Logic
  { unLogic :: ExceptT LogicError (StateT LogicState (Reader LogicEnv)) a }

runLogic :: Logic a -> LogicEnv -> LogicState -> (Either LogicError a, LogicState)
runLogic l c s = runReader (runStateT (runExceptT (unLogic l)) s) c

liftLogic :: Logic a -> App a
liftLogic l = do
  c <- asks appEnvLogic
  s <- get
  let (ea, ls') = runLogic l c (logicState s)
  put s { logicState = ls' }
  either (throwError . AppLogicError) return ea
```

Note that `App` can remain ignorant of the `LogicState` internals.  Just don't export `LogicState`'s constructor.  Then, `App` can't do anything with a `LogicState` other than maintain it on behalf of `Logic`.  Of course, you'll have to arrange to export some function from `Logic` to get an initial `LogicState`.